# Any way to force-reset Snip & Sketch's notification settings?

Tags: windows-10, notifications, action-center, snipping-tool

For about 1+ week ago my Snip & Sketch notifications completely went wako:

- no matter what I select in configuration, I never see on-screen banners; I always have to go to Action Center to see them,
- I see Snip & Sketch's notifications in Action Center even if I disable this functionality.

Here is a pretty example (notifications appears in Action Center even though they shouldn't):

[image]

(Above you can see "Show notifications banners" unchecked, but it was done purely for testing purposes, I have this checkbox checked all the time)

Turning all notifications for  & Sketch on and off brings no effect. Changing checkbox as well, nothing. No matter what is set, switched or checked, notifications always appear in Action Center and never in form of on-screen banners.

I have such problem only with  & Sketch's notifications.

Is there anything to do with this? Any reset? Any workaround?

Comment: Off-topic / can't reproduce question. Snip & Sketch notifications overridden by company security software. Voting to close question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not reproducible and single issue-specific.